# Cannot create a swap chain for 'TCanvasD2D' in Delphi FMX App

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, skia, firemonkey-style, skia4delphi

I've developed a simple app in Delphi FMX, but occasionally very randomly I get this error in my application. It doesn't happen often, but does happen every now and then:

[image: Cannot create a swap chain for 'TCanvasD2D']

I then simply click on "OK" and continue as normal on the app. It doesn't cause any issues and my app functions normally (except one small issue. I can't close the app with the close button on title bar. I'm pressing the button, but nothing is happening. The app isn't closing).

I do not know how to reproduce it or what causes it, does anyone maybe know what this means or what causes it?

---

**Some extra info:**

- I'm using the Skia4Delphi library: https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi
- My app's full source code is on GitHub too: https://github.com/shaunroselt/Roselt-Developer-Tools/
- I'm using styles with a TStyleManager for the look and feel
- I'm using Delphi 11.3 Enterprise
- I'm running Windows 11